# Copy all the content of a JDBCDataSource to another JDBCDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, dbunit

For testing reasons, I need to take a snapshot of a given database which I can access only through JDBC( I don't have command line/administrative access)

I would need to copy all its content in another data source, typically an H2SQLDB backed by a file, so that I can run isolated tests not depending on the original data source.

What is the best approach to clone a JDBC database? I didn't really find any , except using DBUnit export utils to export to XML the first database, and import in a second database.

Comment: LiquiBase (http://www.liquibase.org/) might be overkill, but it'll do the job.

Comment: Tests like this are of limitted value, all you're doing is confirming your code works against HSQLDB but that doesn't necessarily mean it will work with the target database.  Personally I'd save this sort of testing for the acceptance/integration testing phase where I'd use the 'real' database build in the same why the production database will be built at release time.

Comment: I agree with you and I have a different layer of tests for that purpose. The point here is to test again the "content", not a database. It simply a way to store my domain objects somewhere